# Namespaces in CSS and Styling Conflicts

Tags: html, css, namespaces, conflict

I am developing a web product, that when used, it generates code that the users would embed in their site.

The generated code contains HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. And when embedded in a page, it will show along with other content in that page that I have no control over. In other words, the code generated by my product would be embedded in a webpage that already has other content in it. I do not have control over the styling and content of that page.

Now, I am worried about styling naming conflicts. Assume I am using a CSS class named `.amazing-color` and it styles certain components a certain way.

Assume that a web page that uses my code coincidentally had a styling also named `.amazing-color` which would have different styling code, and may overwrite my own styling.

My question is, how can I prevent this from happening? How can I prevent naming conflicts in CSS?

You may suggest that I have complex names for my styles, so I would use `.my-super-amazing-color-212321`, but that would lead to complex CSS classes that are not readable. I think a better solution would be by using namespaces. However I am not sure if there are namespaces in CSS, and if they exist, how can I use them. So, are there name spaces in CSS? Can you provide a sample code on using them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're not asking about namespaces in CSS, but namespaces in *classes*. Classes are an HTML feature, not a CSS one.

Now, there's no formal namespacing mechanism for classes, but a convention in such situations is to use a common abbreviation or initialism as a prefix for all the classes that you use. So you might use "mwp-" for "My Web Product".

Since you are generating the HTML, CSS and JS, you can probably make this prefix configuable, so users of your product can choose a different prefix if it clashes.

Finally, make it clear in your documentation for using your product what prefix you are using and how someone using your product can change the prefix if they need to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a solution I also thought off, however, it may not be a good solution because I am using BEM naming convention (details here: http://getbem.com/).  So, how can I overcome this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a fan of BEM and don't use it, so I can't really advise there. I see no reason why you shouldn't include a common prefix in your block names, but I don't know whether that would violate BEM conventions.

Comment: I understand what you mean regarding BEM. I am using **modified** BEM (or what is called BEVM as described here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwS7M2L07uU ); using this model is more flexible, and helps overcome a lot of disadvantages of BEM. In regards to your question if it violates BEM conventions, I do not think it will violate those conventions, but just makes the code less readable and was hoping to group things via namespaces if possible.